# How to extract string from column scala?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a datafram with values like List[INTERSTED_FIELD:details]. I am trying to get just the interested fields from that. How do I remove the non interesting fields ?

Example :

```
val df = Seq(
  "TESTING:Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low", 
  "PURCHASE:BLACKLIST_ITEM: Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low ", 
   "UNKOWN:#!@", 
   "BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (mejwnw) is blacklisted",
   "BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (1) is blacklisted, UNKOWN:#!@" 
).toDF("raw_type")

df.show(false)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|raw_type                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|TESTING:Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low|
|PURCHASE:BLACKLIST_ITEM: Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low   |
|UNKOWN:#!@                                                       |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (mejwnw) is blacklisted                      |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (1) is blacklisted, UNKOWN:#!@               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to get :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|raw_type                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|TESTING                                                          | 
|PURCHASE,BLACKLIST_ITEM                                          |
|UNKOWN                                                           |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM                                                   |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM, UNKNOWN                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: 1. do you need to print it after comma if more than one interesting fields is in a row?

Comment: Yes. There could more than 1 interesting filed in single string or after comma (examples 2nd row and 5th row)

Comment: interesting fields are all words upper case or word before colon?

Comment: Yeah. All upper case followed by :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this UDF solution

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     |   "TESTING:Testing(2,4, (4,6,7) foo, Foo purchase count 1 is too low",
     |   "PURCHASE:BLACKLIST_ITEM: Foo purchase count (12, 4) is too low ",
     |    "UNKOWN:#!@",
     |    "BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (mejwnw) is blacklisted",
     |    "BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (1) is blacklisted, UNKOWN:#!@"
     | ).toDF("raw_type")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [raw_type: string]

scala> def matchlist(a:String):String=
     | {
     | import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
     | val x = ArrayBuffer[String]()
     | val pt = "([A-Z_]+):".r
     | pt.findAllIn(a).matchData.foreach { m => x.append(m.group(1)) }
     | return x.mkString(",")
     | }
matchlist: (a: String)String

scala> val myudfmatchlist = udf( matchlist(_:String):String )
myudfmatchlist: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.select(myudfmatchlist($"raw_type")).show(false)
+-----------------------+
|UDF(raw_type)          |
+-----------------------+
|TESTING                |
|PURCHASE,BLACKLIST_ITEM|
|UNKOWN                 |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM         |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM,UNKOWN  |
+-----------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: How come the last 'UNKOWN' appears in result?. I tested and I didn't get it.Oh you added it in your input!

Comment: that's the ask.." All upper case followed by :".. go through the comments section.

Comment: I see..But I didn't notice it and worked on it...Now the Input also edited in the question part by you it seems.

Comment: yes.. I also noticed that and edited the question to match.. please work on your rdd solution and post it..

Answer (score 1):

```
val p = "[A-Z_]+(?=:)".r
df.rdd.map(x=>p.findAllIn(x.mkString).mkString(",")).toDF(df.columns:_*).show(false)
```

***In spark-shell:***

```
scala> df.rdd.map(x=>p.findAllIn(x.mkString).mkString(",")).toDF(df.columns:_*).show(false)
+-----------------------+
|raw_type               |
+-----------------------+
|TESTING                |
|PURCHASE,BLACKLIST_ITEM|
|UNKOWN                 |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM         |
|BLACKLIST_ITEM,UNKOWN  |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: the last entry is "BLACKLIST_ITEM:item (1) is blacklisted, UNKOWN:#!@ "..

Comment: still simplified using `lookahead positive(?=)` in regex.

Comment: concise and expressive rdd solution!.. kudos.